# C - My decrementing for loop works, but unsure why

Tags: c, cs50

I tried to search for a similar question already asked, but could not find one. Code is at end of post. Thank you for your time.

---

**Problem:** Though my code works correctly for the assignment, I am unsure why my *for loop* only works as stated.

To clarify what my code is supposed to do: *Take a number entered by the User and build two half pyramids: one decrementing and one incrementing.*

Here is an image example: [Pyramid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Vgf.png)

---

**Question:** In my current decrementing *for loop*, I have: `for (int s = u - y; s > 1; s--)`

That *for loop* works. But when I try `for (int s = u - 1; s > 1; s--)` or `for (int s = u; s > 1; s--)`, it doesn't decrement.

Why does this *for loop* only decrement if I **subtract using the *y* variable**?

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get a number value from User (u) that is between 1 and 8.
    int u;
    do
    {
        u = get_int("Type a number: \n");
    }
    while (u < 1 || u > 8);


   // Print a new line each loop, until reaching User number (u)
   for (int y = 0; y < u; y++)
   {
        // Print a "." by (u - 1) number of times. Subtract another "." each loop
        for (int s = u - y; s > 1; s--)
        {
            printf(".");
        }

        // Print a "#" by (y) number of times. Add another "#" each loop
        for (int width = 0; width <= y; width++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @hunfben, welcome to StackOverflow. Your variable `u` doesn't change anywhere, right? Then if `u = 8`, `u - 1` will always be 7 so the `s` for loop will always go from 7 to 1 and print exactly 6 dots. `y` in the other hand is the variable that goes from 0 to `u`, meaning each time `y` changes, `s = u - y` changes, and so does the number of printed dots.

Comment: Why are you tagging a question about C with C++?

Comment: @ChoKaPeek Thank you for the welcome and thank you for your help! Your answer makes complete sense. 

I believe I misunderstood how the for loop worked then. I assumed once `s` was initialized in the for loop, it did not change, and that the `s--` is what caused the actual decrementing in value. I still have a lot to learn here, thank you so much for your response!

Comment: @Eric I apologize, I am used to forums/social media sites where you have to cast a wider net with tags to get a response. I'll be sure to stick to only related tags from now on, seeing as this community is a lot more responsive and helpful than others!

Answer (score 0):

ChoKaPeek answered the question in the comments. Here's another approach, using C's formatted output's ability to specify a variable field width:

```
        char* dots = "........";
        char* octos = "########";
        for (int nOctos=0; nOctos <= u; nOctos++) {
            printf("%.*s%.*s\n", u-nOctos, dots, nOctos, octos);
        }
```

Breaking it down:

`%s` means "I'm passing a `char*` in the parameter list"

the `.` means "using a field width"

the `*` means "the field width is in the parameter before the `char*`"